# Sync free tagging vocabulary

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I've a content type article, where user can create new terms to a vocabulary through free-tagging for example content, color and so on . When the user creates a new content, he can add new terms to the categories. Now I'd like to provide the new created terms also to be available in my forum vocabulary, so user can discuss about this terms in the forum.
I've assigned the vocabulary to my article and to my forum. But that alone does not work the way, I'd like to.
In the meanwhile I'm using the [Taxonomy Manager](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) for just copying the terms from the 'article' vocabulary to the 'forum' vocabulary.
But that's not the best solution for me, cause I've to manually do this for every added term.
It would be great, if this could happened 'on the fly', some kind of automatically.
Can anybody please help me to get this working?
Please also let me know, if the problem is not getting clear to you.
Thanx for your suggestions.

Comment: maybe I just don't completely understand what you are trying to do. You open to this, have 2 vocabularies, 1 for articles & forums, the other just for forums?  The trouble is then combining the 2 fields in one for forums.

Comment: Hi iStryker, thanx for your feedback. I edited my post a little bit, to make it, so I hope, become more clear.

Comment: @dennis605: Any reason you are not using the same vocabulary for both?

Answer (score 1):

1. Assign the same vocab to both content types.
2. Install the [Tagging module](http://drupal.org/project/tagging)
3. Now the fields should have auto suggest for the fields, as the user types